# Trying to get property of non-object in PHP (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know that *mysql_* functions are deprecated, but this is what I'm using right now because I will be using Highcharts.

Aside from that, my problem is here in this code LINE 12 (i.e. the `if else` conditional):

```
<?php
    include ('db/database_configuration.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{           
    $UserName = $_POST['username'];         
    $UserPassword = $_POST['password']; 
    $result = @mysql_query("SELECT `tblusers`.`username`, `tblusers`.`password` FROM tblusers
            WHERE ((`tblusers`.`username` = '$UserName') AND (`tblusers`.`password` = '$UserPassword'))");


                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      $as = $row['account_stat'];
                if ($as == "Administrator") {
                setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $myuser;
                header("location:administrator.php?user=$myuser");
                } else {
                setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $myuser;
                header("location:standard_user.php?user=$myuser");
                }
                    }
                } else {
                    print '
                  <div class="w3-panel w3-red">
                    <h3>Error!</h3>
                    <p>Account not found.</p>
                  </div> 
                ';
                }
        }
?>
```

This `If else` conditional utilizes a *mysqli_* function, but I decided to go back to a *mysql_* function because the code also uses highcharts. 
Could anyone help me to convert this `If else` conditional to using a *mysqli_* function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: highcharts does not require mysql_*

Comment: @Dagon sir my highcharts require mysql(THE database) in php to show specific data

Comment: your confusing the db with the db api. mysql_* and mysqli_ are API's

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to use mysql, you can do:

```
if ( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: It works sir Thanks! a little problem , if I logged in the admin = it goes to the header standard_user.php

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$as` and `$row` and see if you're getting the correct data. The value may not be "Administrator" or  the column on $row may not be ['account_stat'].

Comment: It is correct sir. it is Administrator and it is in the account_stat column

Comment: Are you still being redirected? If yes, can you do a `var_dump( $as )` and `die();` right before the header redirect to standard user and let us know what that came up with? And no sirs! We're all colleagues here. :)